# Pass parameters to a Java Applet from Java Program

Tags: java, parameters, applet

I want to change the os.name property before invoking an applet.

(Using appletviewer -J-Dos.name=Windows on Linux raises a lot of exceptions, understandably so)

So, I figured I'll use System.setProperty() to set the os name in a Java Program (i.e. the JVM on starting will have the correct OS name, but the applet won't) and then invoke the applet from there (by calling it's init() function)

The issue is I don't know how to pass the parameters to the applet (the ones I'd normally be using the param HTML tag for.)?

Any ideas?

I think it might be possible by implementing the AppletStub interface, but I'm not sure how to implement the other methods (apart from getParameter).

Comment: Why do you want to change os.name? Surely the applet when run will have the correct value? For examplke on windows os.name = "Windows 7"

Comment: I'm doing some dynamic analysis on applets. Since, some applets check the OS and continue only when it's windows, I need to "spoof" my OS for the applet to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [browse the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/applet/AppletViewer.java) of the `appletviewer` from the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) for ideas, or even reuse its code for your purposes. However, it is possible to display an applet in less code than that, if you don't need all the features of Oracle's appletviewer.  I found [this one from Ian F. Darwin](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AppletViewerasimpleAppletViewerprogram.htm), or even this [post from Sandeep Sharma](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fd0172/how-to-create-your-own-appletviewer-in-java/) which seems to be a really stripped-down version.